# SQL - multiple conditions in DCount() function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access 2007.

```
A: DCount("[Name]","[Main]","[Name] = 'Mark'")/
   DCount("[Entry]","[Main]","[Entry] = 1")
```

Okay, so I am basically counting the number of people with the name Mark and I am dividing it by the number of Entry's that = 1 in my database. That's easy enough, but I am trying to apply a third condition, where

> [Location]![City] = 'Chicago'

, but Access isn't letting me do this (It can't find the table, even though it's in the table I specified above.

```
   DCount("[Name]","[Main]","[Name] = 'Mark' AND [Location]![City] = 'Chicago'")/
   DCount("[Entry]","[Main]","[Entry] = 1")
```

I have also tried filtering the city with a Where clause in the Design view, but the condition is being applied after the calculation above, so the calculation is the same regardless of the city. I just need it to perform the above calculation for the city of Chicago.

Is something like this possible with DCount?

Also, I would die a happy man if you could tell me how to Group By the city While performing the calculations for each one separately, but I would also be very thankful if someone could just show me how to do it the first way too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is [Location]![City]?  My answer is based on the presumption it refers to a field named City in a table named Location.

If that is correct, I think your problem is because you're attempting to specify a condition based on a field which is not part of the *domain* ([Main]) you told DCount to use.

From [Microsoft's Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211471%28office.11%29.aspx), the domain is "*A string expression identifying the set of records that constitutes the domain. It can be a table name or a query name for a query that does not require a parameter.*"

So if you want your DCount *criteria* to refer to fields in two tables, consolidate the tables in the form of a query into a single "domain".  Maybe your query could be something like this, "qryMainWithCity":

```
SELECT m.[Name], m.Entry, m.City_ID, l.City
FROM
    Main AS m
    INNER JOIN Location AS l
    ON m.City_ID = l.City_ID;
```

If that query works for your situation, you should be able to get what you want with a DCount expression like this:

```
DCount("*","qryMainWithCity","[Name] = 'Mark' AND City = 'Chicago'")
```

Comment: Thanks Hans, you have helped several times now and I really appreciate it. So this would work on a cross tab query right?

Comment: You're welcome, Jerry.  I suppose it could work in a cross tab, but I'm not really the one to ask about them because I seldom use them.  If you run into trouble, you know how to ask a question on here.  Right?  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was just posting the same answer as @HansUp's came up. I have an alternative way to do it, and that's to use an instant recordset lookup:

```
  Dim varReturnValue as Variant

  varReturnValue = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT Main.[Name] FROM Main INNER JOIN Location ON Main.City_ID = Location.City_ID WHERE Main.[Name] = 'Mark' AND Location.City = 'Chicago';")(0)
```

That returns the first field in the recordset returned (the index is zero-based). That way you don't have to save a query.

Comment: Thanks David, you are always helping me too, I appreciate it.